# Replace more than one instance on a character with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried:

```
var test = code.replace("-", "%2D");
```

but if code = "1-2-3", it only replaces one dash. How do I replace both?

Comment: use a regex match.. `/-/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use //

```
var test = code.replace(/-/g, "%2D");
```

Comment: Can you explain what `/.../` is? What does the `g` do?

Comment: If i remember correctly g means global and /.../ is to initiate a regex expression